# How to read JSON object in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I want to read status and message object of this JSON.
I have tried `json_decode()` but its not working fine.

JSON:

```
{"d":"{\"successMessage\":\"24 rows added / updated\",\"failMessage\":null,\"status\":true}"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please use the following code

```
$json = '{"d":"{\"successMessage\":\"24 rows added / updated\",\"failMessage\":null,\"status\":true}"}';

echo "<pre>";
$myArr = json_decode($json, true);
$varArr = json_decode($myArr["d"]);
print_r($varArr)."<hr>";
echo $varArr->successMessage;
```

and it will give output as

```
stdClass Object
(
    [successMessage] => 24 rows added / updated
    [failMessage] => 
    [status] => 1
)
24 rows added / updated
```